# how to get the content from external url when that page is fully loaded?

Tags: php

```
$data = array();

$html = file_get_html('www.example.com');


foreach($html->find(".bidsTable tr") as $tr){
    $row = array();
    foreach($tr->find("td") as $td){
        /* enter code here */
       $row[] = $td->plaintext;
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

I am using this code to get the content from external url but I do not get the full html code is there any way to get the content when that page is fully loaded.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That code *does* wait until it's fully loaded. What it won't do, though, is execute JavaScript, so if your desired content is loaded after page load via AJAX or something, doing this in PHP just won't work.

Comment: you will need to use something like `phantomjs` if you want to get javascript stuff.

Comment: Yes may be.so what should be the alternative?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` should do what you want.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, it probably won't - it sounds like OP's data is loaded via JS.

Comment: I didn't get that @ceejayoz but *c'est la vie*

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL to get HTML content,

try like this, It will certainly wait until content is loaded.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

foreach($html->find(".bidsTable tr") as $tr){
$row = array();
foreach($tr->find("td") as $td){
  /* enter code here */
  $row[] = $td->plaintext;
}
$data[] = $row;
}
```